Как сделать парсинг плейлиста ВКонтакте? PHP
Всем добрый день! Подскажите как спарсить количество прослушиваний в плейлисте ВК на PHP?
Я пробовал реализовать это через Curl, DOM, file_get_content, Goutte - не парсит. Вероятно, проблема в том, что ВК динамически подгружает эти данные и все эти способы не могут получить их, а API для этих целей попросту нет.
Какие варианты решения данной проблемы ещё есть?
